# How do I assign multiple variables based on other columns values from select (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

Hi I'm fairly new to this, wondering how to assign values to multiple variables from a select statement so that i can use them in apex.

```
DECLARE
emails_hr varchar2(2000);
emails_ops varchar2(2000);
emails_finance varchar2(2000);
emails_sales varchar2(2000);
BEGIN

SELECT
  DEPARTMENT,
  LISTAGG(lower(EMAIL), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DISPLAY_AREA) as EMAILS
FROM (
  select
    DEPARTMENT,
    EMAIL 
from CONTACT_TABLE
    where EMAIL is not NULL
    and OFFICE_ID = 100
 )
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT;

END;
```

The select query returns this:

```
DEPARTMENT          EMAILS                  

human resources     abby@gmail.com                  
operations          bob@gmail.com; carol@gmail.com; dave@gmail.com  
finance             emma@gmail.com; fred@gmail.com          
sales               gary@gmail.com; harry@gmail.com; ian@gmail.com
```

It's expecting an INTO clause so I tried putting the LISTAGG part in a case statement to select into the variables based on department, but I can't get it to a point where I don't just get a syntax error.

EDIT: I should mention, not all offices have all 4 departments

My head hurts, thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What do you want to do with the query results in the PL/SQL code? Perhaps you require a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7115C8B6-62F9-496D-BEC3-F7441DFE148A)?

Comment: That's most probably a wrong approach, as you'd have to declare as many variables as there are departments (hr, ops, finance, ...) and - if new department is established - you'd have to fix that code. Besides, you'd have to write as many SELECT ... INTO statements as there are departments. And if you put OFFICE_ID into the query, number of variables would become *enormous*. So, which problem are you actually trying to solve? Maybe you should use a collection (as @Abra already commented), or something else; can't tell.

Comment: I want to have buttons on the page 'Email all HR', 'Email all Sales' etc. The office/department stuff is just an example, I did that because the actual data is specific to my organisation/very 'jargony' - there won't ever be any new ones, but yeah there are a lot more than 4.

I'm not sure if a collection would work because since not all 'offices' are always present, the indexes for each dept would be different for different sites?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is hard to work out exactly what you want to do but I think you might be after a cursor.....

```
DECLARE
   emails_hr varchar2(2000);
   emails_ops varchar2(2000);
   emails_finance varchar2(2000);
   emails_sales varchar2(2000);

   CURSOR C_DEPARTMENTS IS       
   SELECT DEPARTMENT,
     LISTAGG(lower(EMAIL), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DISPLAY_AREA) as EMAILS
   FROM (SELECT DEPARTMENT, EMAIL 
         FROM  CONTACT_TABLE
         WHERE EMAIL is not NULL
         AND   OFFICE_ID = 100
   )
  GROUP BY DEPARTMENT;

BEGIN
  FOR v_row in c_departments LOOP
    -- do whatever you want in here eg
    dbms_output.put_line('department = ' || v_row.department);
    dbms_output.put_line('emails = ' || v_row.emails);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This is what I needed, yeah apologies for the vague question I didn't explain it well, and am also not well versed in all the correct terms for things yet being quite new to this. With this I was able to do a case statement to assign the email rows to the variables emails_hr, emails_ops etc. Thanks very much